When sending multipart/data, network error is coming in expo, while the data is getting saved successfully
I am working in expo development build and i am sending a multipart data like this
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('userServiceId', chatid);
  formData.append('senderId', 'noneed');
  formData.append('ifAgent', true);
  formData.append('messageType', 'image');
  formData.append('size',fileSizeToShow)
  formData.append('messageText', data.fileName);
  formData.append('mimeType',`data:${data.mimeType};base64,`);
  formData.append('file',`data:${data.mimeType};base64,` + compressedImage.data, 
  data.fileName )
  formData.append('timestamp', new Date());

    // Send data to the backend
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_PORT}/chat/savechatapp`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error.message || error);
    }

Here i am getting the error,  "Error uploading image: Network Error"
and this is my backend when saving chat data
  export const saveChat = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    let newdoc;
     let newimage;
    if(req.userId){
     req.body.senderId = req.userId;
     }
     if (req.body.messageType === "image") {
  const base64Image = req.body.file;
  const base64Data = base64Image.split(",")[1];
  const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, "base64");

  try {
    // Wait for sharp to resize the image and get the thumbnail buffer
    const thumbnailBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer).resize(100, 100).toBuffer();

    // Convert the thumbnail buffer back to base64 and save it in req.body
    const thumbnailBase64 = thumbnailBuffer.toString("base64");
    req.body.thumbnail = thumbnailBase64;

    // Prepare the new image data
    newimage = {
      data: imageBuffer,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error creating thumbnail: ", err);
  }

  // Remove the file from req.body
  delete req.body.file
} else if (req.body.messageType === "docs") {
  const docsBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body.file, "base64");
  newdoc = docsBuffer;
  delete req.body.file;
}
const chat = await Chat.create(req.body);
if (req.body.messageType === "docs" && chat) {
  const docs = await Chat.Docs.create({
    chatId: chat._id,
    data: newdoc,
    mimeType: req.body.mimeType,
  });
  docs.save();
}else if (req.body.messageType === "image" && newimage && chat) {
    newimage.chatId=chat._id;
    const image = await Chat.Images.create(newimage);
    image.save();
       }
      // console.log("Chat creaeted succeessfully", chat);
       res.status(200).send({ data: chat });
       } catch (err) {
       res.status(500).send({ error: err.message });
       console.log("found there error", err.message);
       }
          };

However the data, which is image is saving without any problem and sending data as needed . But in frontend which is expo app in development mode is giving network error. Please help.
